# How to detect that there is no item of predefined categories on photo with keras NN?

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network

I try to implement face recognition for a set of faces. For solution I use a basic neural network in Keras.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(65, 3, 3, input_shape=(1, 50, 50)))
....
model.add(Dense(persons_cnt, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

There is set of grayscale images with size of 50x50px on input layer, vectors like [0 1 0 ...] on output layer.

Everything works fine when I test model with photos with persons from training set. But if I call `model.predict()` with a photo of random stranger, I always get decision that there is one person from training set.For example for two persons I always get answers `[1, 0]` or `[0, 1]` and there is no way to get answer `[0, 0]` or at least `[0.5, 0.5]` (is last one possible sometimes?).

I tried also to add to training set strangers and to assign new category for them (training output for them is `[0, 0, 1]`). But in this case my NN can't compute appropriate weights for ages.

So is there any way to recognize persons from predefined set and ignore others?

Comment: What do you mean by "weights for ages"? Is your question how to add a 'unknown/stranger' output to your network?

Comment: @nemo I mean that it can iterate through thousands and thousands of epochs, and accuracy remains almost unchanged. And yes, you have correctly understood my question.